# QT multicast sender doesnt multicast message through IPv4 but works fine with IPv6

Tags: network-programming, ip, qt-creator

I am trying to multicast a message to ip address "239.255.43.21". I build the QT-creator example project "Qt\Examples\Qt-5.15.2\network\multicastsender". When I run the code it looks like working fine. However, when I check the wireshark I can only see IPv6 multicasts. On different computers the code works fine. I believe something is wrong with my OS? I am using LattePanda Alpha as a computer. I also am setting my IPv4 address manually, Could this be a problem ?

To check the firewall `sudo ufw status` returns inactive.

Check and change `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmo_echo_ignore_broadcast` to 1 and 0.

Both didn't works.

Thank you in advance!